# i'm confused with CoordConv

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

i read a paper which written by uber lab
https://medium.com/@Cambridge_Spark/coordconv-layer-deep-learning-e02d728c2311
they create a network named Coordconv,and in this coordconv they not only add two layer of meshgrid but also with a simple conv net.

1. it said through this way they add positional info to every pixel points?
   2.so that after conv the pixel points still remain in same place as in original image?
2. and this is also working to add two layers of meshgrid to freature maps which draw from neural network?
3. how could Meshgrid help add positional info to the image?
4. Does this just simply added two layers which are the same size as the original image but is in[-1,1] meshgrid to original input image?

a big THANKS in advance!

Answer (score 1):

## About CoordConv

Here is the original paper which proposed the CoordConv layer: [CoordConv paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.03247.pdf).

I will try to convey my instinctive undersanding of this operation.

## How AddCoords works

The way the information is added is by stacking (***concatenating***, to be more accurate) two new 2D tensors to the data. Those two channels are not multiplied together, therefore there is no meshgrid involved in this process.

Say we are at a specific layer of the network. The last convolution step produced 4 2D-tensors of shape `8x8`, each of which is the result of the previous convolution by a filter (thus we had 4 kernels in the previous step). They are in reality stacked in a single tensor of size `bs * 8 * 8 * 4` where `bs` is the *batch size*, but let's ignore the batch size from now.

The `AddCoords` method will create two other 2D tensors:

`xx_channel`:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
 [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
 [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
 [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
 [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]]
```

and `yy_channel`:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Those are the results of the matmuls of the `tf.range` by the `tf.ones`.

They will then be scaled to fit in the range `[-1, 1]` and casted to tensorflow.float32 type:

`xx_channel`:

```
[[-1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ],
 [-0.71428571, -0.71428571, -0.71428571, -0.71428571, -0.71428571, -0.71428571, -0.71428571, -0.71428571],
 [-0.42857143, -0.42857143, -0.42857143, -0.42857143, -0.42857143, -0.42857143, -0.42857143, -0.42857143],
 [-0.14285714, -0.14285714, -0.14285714, -0.14285714, -0.14285714, -0.14285714, -0.14285714, -0.14285714],
 [ 0.14285714,  0.14285714,  0.14285714,  0.14285714,  0.14285714,  0.14285714,  0.14285714,  0.14285714],
 [ 0.42857143,  0.42857143,  0.42857143,  0.42857143,  0.42857143,  0.42857143,  0.42857143,  0.42857143],
 [ 0.71428571,  0.71428571,  0.71428571,  0.71428571,  0.71428571,  0.71428571,  0.71428571,  0.71428571],
 [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ]]
```

`yy_channel`:

```
[[-1., -0.71428571, -0.42857143, -0.14285714,  0.14285714, 0.42857143,  0.71428571,  1.],
 [-1., -0.71428571, -0.42857143, -0.14285714,  0.14285714, 0.42857143,  0.71428571,  1.],
 [-1., -0.71428571, -0.42857143, -0.14285714,  0.14285714, 0.42857143,  0.71428571,  1.],
 [-1., -0.71428571, -0.42857143, -0.14285714,  0.14285714, 0.42857143,  0.71428571,  1.],
 [-1., -0.71428571, -0.42857143, -0.14285714,  0.14285714, 0.42857143,  0.71428571,  1.],
 [-1., -0.71428571, -0.42857143, -0.14285714,  0.14285714, 0.42857143,  0.71428571,  1.],
 [-1., -0.71428571, -0.42857143, -0.14285714,  0.14285714, 0.42857143,  0.71428571,  1.],
 [-1., -0.71428571, -0.42857143, -0.14285714,  0.14285714, 0.42857143,  0.71428571,  1.]]
```

They will then be concatenated to the other 2D-tensors along the last dimension ("-1"), ending up with a 3D-tensor with shape `8 * 8 * 6`(again, the dimension of the batch size is ignored in my explanation).

Those two generated channels are what the authors in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.03247.pdf) call **coordinate informations**. The method literally adds the coordinates of each 2D position : the y-coord and the x-coord.

In our example, let's consider the values of an input tensor at position `[4, 5]`,  meaning the values along the last dimension (size 4), which is accessible like this : `input_tensor[4, 5, :]`. It may return something like this :

```
input_tensor[4, 5, :]
# > [0.75261177, 0.62114716, 0.76845441, 0.44747785]
```

After `AddCoords`, it becomes:

```
ret[4, 5, :]
# > [0.75261177, 0.62114716, 0.76845441, 0.44747785, 0.14285714, 0.42857143]
```

... where `0.14285714` is the scaled value of **4 *ie its y-coord*** and `0.42857143` is the scaled value of **5 *ie its x-coord***. The information about coordinates is now contained inside the resulting tensor, which is returned by the `AddCoords` method.

## The CoordConv

It's a designed layer that applies `AddCoords` to the input and feeds the resulting tensor to a classic Conv2D layer. As such, it can be added to a neural network, as you would do with a Conv2D layer.

That's what the authors did, when experimenting with GANs for example, where they substitued `Conv2D` with `CoordConv` (which, again, includes a Conv2D).

Let me know if that answers your questions and/or correct any misconceptions.

## What does it imply for the neural network ?

### More trainable parameters...

Let's give a bit more context to our previous example.
In our previous example, the last layer yielded a tensor with shape `8 x 8 x 4`. Let's say we want the next convolution layer to yield 16 output filters, from a convolution window of 3 * 3.

> You can see [this link to get what convolution does mathematically ,
> chapter 2.1](https://learnopencv.com/image-classification-using-convolutional-neural-networks-in-keras/) . You can get a basic understanding of [what the
> convolution operation yields thanks to this visualizer](https://ezyang.github.io/convolution-visualizer/index.html). Just keep
> in mind both links show a single kernel and a single channel input
> matrix.

- If we don't add the coordinate tensors, the convolution to come will have 16 kernels with shape `3 x 3 x 4` each.
- If we do apply AddCoords, we will feed a tensor with shape `8 x 8 x 6` instead, and our 16 kernels will each have the shape `3 x 3 x 6`.

You can think of those kernels as neurons. Each neuron has `3 x 3 x 4 == 36`  weights (Conv2D) or `3 x 3 x 6 == 54` weights (AddCoords+Conv2D, or CoordConv). Their weights will be updated during the learning process. Knowing this, it should appear evident that the coordinates channels of CoordConv implies new and specific weights to each kernel of the convolution layer. That's how the neural network takes into consideration these coordinates.

### ... implied in similar training processes

If you haven't been experimenting with Machine Learning, the supervised learning process of a neural network might be quite complex to comprehend, but it's more general and could be resumed (oversimplified) as:

- We calculate the error, which is a mathematical way to describe how
  far the prediction is from the ground truth. Then we update (add)
  each parameter (or weight) in the network, layer after layer from the
  output layer to the input one, by a value that represents its
  implication in this error and the direction it should take to decrease the error. This process is called "backpropagation of
  the error".

Comment: Firstly A BIG THANKS TO YOUR EXTRAORDINARY EXPLANATION!!!and indeed your amazing answer solved most part of my confusion!but still have some little trouble want to ask:just add two layers which contains the (x,y) coordinate that could make the convolution smoothly convert the points in the original image to the new image?does this have some sort of mathematics reasons?the convolution process knows how to add it to new image?

Comment: I'm glad it was useful. I tried to add insights about the effect of adding the coordinate channels, but I am not sure of what you mean by "new image".

Comment: "new image" is the result of coordconv, the new image created by coordconv.

Comment: Yes I updated my answer to address this. Those images are called `feature maps` but I refer to them as "resulting tensors" in my answer.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH FOR YOUR UPDATE!!!!!!!!!!!!i understand it clearly！！best wishes to u！！！